# Assembly wrong implementation of memmove?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att

I am trying to implement something similar to memmove in assembly, I wrote:

```
.global _start

.section .text
_start:

movl $0, %eax
start:
    movb source(%eax), %cl
    movb %cl, destination(%eax)
    inc %eax
    cmp num, %eax
    jne start

end:
```

But for some reason my program doesn't work when num isn't a multiplication of 4 like 1 or 2, I can't find what is wrong with my code...

I know for sure that num is a positive 4 bytes, and so is every element in both arrays.

Example of such input file (using external run_test.sh file to merge both):

```
  xorl %ecx, %ecx
  movq $source, %rbx
  movq $destination, %rdx

checkcorrectness:
  movl (%rdx,%rcx,4), %r8d
  cmpl (%rbx,%rcx,4), %r8d
  jne bad_exit
  incl %ecx
  movl num, %r9d
  shrl $2, %r9d
  cmpl %r9d, %ecx
  jne checkcorrectness

  movq $60, %rax
  movq $0, %rdi
  syscall

bad_exit:
  movq $60, %rax
  movq $1, %rdi
  syscall

.section .data
source: .int 6,12,9,8
destination: .int 1,2,9,4 # expected: .int 6,2,3,4
num: .int 1
```

The result is:

```
FAIL
```

My run test file **Which I can't change**:

```
#!/bin/bash

YOUR_ASM=$1
TEST=$2
TEST_NAME=$(basename -- "${TEST}")
cat "$YOUR_ASM" "$TEST" > merged.asm

as merged.asm -o merged.o
if [ -f "merged.o" ]; then
    ld merged.o -o merged.out
    if [ -f "merged.out" ]; then
        timeout 120s ./merged.out   
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "${YOUR_ASM} tested with ${TEST_NAME}: PASS"
            STATUS=0
        else
            echo "${YOUR_ASM} tested with ${TEST_NAME}: FAIL"
            STATUS=1
        fi
    else
        echo "${YOUR_ASM} could not be created (ld stage) with ${TEST_NAME}: FAIL"
        STATUS=1    
    fi
else
    echo "${YOUR_ASM} could not be created (as stage) with ${TEST_NAME}: FAIL"
    STATUS=1        
fi

rm merged.*
exit ${STATUS}
```

Comment: That's not a [mcve]. Also you should zero `eax`. Other than that it looks like it should work.

Comment: @Jester will add all code even that it's long

Comment: Also also the "expected" is wrong. By copying a single byte, you are going to get `6,2,9,4` and indeed I do get that. No idea where you even got a `3` from.

Comment: @Jester thanks, fixed the typo and added all needed info

Comment: It looks like you compare data past the end of the array.  If the random bytes after the array ends don't match, you get a spurious mismatch.

Comment: I don't get it, is the problem with my code? since run_test.sh file is from my professor and he says it's fine

Comment: The `shrl $2, %r9d` will turn a `1` into a `0` and since you already did `incl %ecx` the `jne` will loop back instead of stopping. The whole thing makes little sense, since the check code specifically uses 32 bit values.

Comment: But on the one hand I can't change that code (only the first part I published) on the other hand my professor want the code to support not only multiplies of 4 bytes... how can I solve this? If I change num to 4 or 8 or 12 everything works fine... @Jester

Comment: @john Get back to your professor and point out the problem.

Comment: already did that and he insists that the problem is in my code (the first part I published on top)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine (for `memcpy` but not `memmove`), see below for comments on that.

---

**The check code is buggy for `num: .int 1` (or any byte-count less than 4).**
Using `jne` instead of `jb` means it will loop until ECX wraps around back to 0, after checking 2^32 dwords (or segfaulting or finding a mismatch first).  In C terms, it looks like this.

```
uint32_t ecx = 0;
do{
    ...
    ecx++;
}while(ecx != num>>2);
```

Using `} while( ecx < (num>>2) );` would partially fix the bug, although it would still "FAIL" for non-multiple-of-4 byte counts if the source and destination weren't already the same except for the low byte of each dword.  (So copying even the first byte of a new dword chunk is enough to make the whole dword match.)

(Using dword compares to implement memcmp is a similar problem to vectorizing a loop with wide SIMD vectors: for correctness you have to discard or ignore data from past the end of the *actual* input, for odd sizes that aren't a multiple of the chunk size you're using.  e.g. mask or shift to discard data from outside the area you're supposed to be looking at in the final iteration, or use a byte loop for cleanup.)

---

If you single-step with GDB and watch registers change (`layout reg`), this is obvious:

- The first `mov` / `cmp` / `jne bad_exit` passes successfully
- `inc ecx` produces `1`
- R9D = 1 after the load
- SHR produces `0`
- **`cmp %r9d, %ecx / jne checkcorrectness` loops back to the top, to check the 2nd dword,** because 1 != 0.  Of course that dword doesn't match because `num = 1` told you not to copy it.

You mentioned in comments that your professor hasn't realized their code is buggy.  Feel free to link them this answer.  The only way this could work is if you used `num: .int 4` or `5` or more.

---

**Your code is fine for `memcpy`, but not `memmove`; it would break if the src and dst *partially* overlapped.**  [C `memmove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove) produces a result "as if the characters were copied to a temporary character array and then the characters were copied from the array to dest."  The usual way to do that is to check for overlap, and if so then copy in the reverse direction.

It's also inefficient in several ways beyond being simplistic 1-byte-at-a-time, e.g.

- re-reading the count from memory every iteration instead of loading once into a register.  x86-64 has lots of registers; use them.
- Using 32-bit address size instead of `source(%rax)` is worse for no reason; `mov $0, %eax` already zero-extends into RAX, and 64-bit is the natural / default address-width.  (Of course, `source(%rax)` still needs the `source` absolute address to fit in a 32-bit sign-extended value in the machine code, but this is an option in a Linux non-PIE executable.)
- Merging a new byte into the bottom of RCX instead instead of `movzbl source(%eax), %ecx`.  (`mov %cl, destination(%rax)` is the only way to do a byte store, but loads have a choice of zero-extending the byte into the full register to avoid any dependency on the old value.)

Comment: ״The only way this could work is if you used num: .int 4 or 5 or more.״ But I get fail with 5 too... Plus I can suppose that the src and dst are in different places in memory

Comment: @john: I get PASS with `num: .int 5` with your source files from the question otherwise unmodified, using your run script.  And if you can assume that src and dst don't overlap at all, then you're implementing memcpy, not memmove.  (That is also "similar to memmove" I guess, but I assumed you meant the difference from memmove was only in that you had hard-coded label names instead of function args, for no apparent reason because that doesn't make it any easier.)